# deleting duplication of list value in python

Tags: python, list, csv, calculation

I have a list,

```
list1 = [[1,4,0,0],[2,0,1,0],[9,8,4,0],[0,2,5,3]]
```

and this list is like this;

```
list1 =[[d[x][y] for y in key] for x in key]
```

so when I write this `list1` using `writer.writerows(list1)`, its excel table shows this:

```
1 4 0 0
2 0 1 0
9 8 4 0 
0 2 5 3
```

and as you know, its not symmetrical, I made a new list,

```
list2 = [[d[x][y]+d[y][x] for y in key] for x in key]
```

I could have made this table in the excel file:

```
2 6 9 0
6 0 9 2
9 9 8 5
0 2 5 6
```

but here comes the problem. I have to make a file that if `x==y`, in `d[x][y]` then its values should not be calculated. So I want my result to be like this:

```
1 6 9 0 
6 0 9 2
9 9 4 5 
0 2 5 3
```

FYI, I've used:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(int))
keys = sorted(d)
```

how can I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a double list comprehension, and the a ternary operator to select when to add the elements:

#### Code:

```
list2 = [[list1[x][y] + list1[y][x] if x != y else list1[x][y]
          for x in range(len(list1))] for y in range(len(list1[0]))]
```

#### Test Code:

```
list1 = [[1, 4, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0], [9, 8, 4, 0], [0, 2, 5, 3]]
list2 = [[list1[x][y] + list1[y][x] if x != y else list1[x][y]
          for x in range(len(list1))] for y in range(len(list1[0]))]
print(list2)
```

#### Results:

```
[[1, 6, 9, 0], [6, 0, 9, 2], [9, 9, 4, 5], [0, 2, 5, 3]]
```